# php mysql İf user input has spaces, the commands dont work

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code that user can add categories and add subcategories of added categories. if the category names have blanks (Word1 word2 word3), then category is added to database correctly but when i add subcategories to it, it doesnt work. Let me explain. Lets say i have a category named "No real person involved". When i try to add subcategories for this; my code doesnt work. but it works when category name contains only one word.

Anyway lets say my categori name is $a
and my subcategori name is $b;

i take these values within a form and send them to another page called insert.php.

in insert.php , the code is;

```
$id = "select categori_id from categori where categoriname = '$a'";
$veri2 =$conn->query($id);
while($bilgi = $veri2->fetch_assoc())
  {
      $ci = $bilgi['kategoriid'];  

      $sorgu2 = "insert into altkategori(subcategoriname, categori_id) values('$b','$ci')";
      $conn->query($sorgu2);
      echo "subcategori added";
  }
  $conn->close();
```

so this doesnt work when categori has spaces.i m not sure if i explained it nice.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: Please show us more code. Try running same query directly in mysql console. Is output as expected ?

Comment: Okey let me try one more. I have categories in my database. and i want to add each of them subcategories. I want to have a form in my mainpage. which has select option values for all categories. . and also has an input text for subcategory name. i think the problem is; if the select value contains a couple words, the posted data takes only the first word as the selected item. that causes the error. idk how to post select-option value that contains a couple word.

Answer (score 0):

okey i know i couldnt explain it nice, but i solved it. if anyone understands the problem and has the same problem: here is solution.

the true select option part must have been like this;

```html
  <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" name="altt">
  <option selected>Seçiniz</option>
  
  <?php
  
  $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','egitimdeneme');
  $sorgu4 = "select kategoriadi from kategori";
  $veri4 = $conn->query($sorgu4);
  while($bilgi = $veri4->fetch_assoc())
  {
   $ci = $bilgi['kategoriadi'];
   echo "<option value='$ci'>$ci</option>";
  }
    
  echo "</select>";
  
  ?>
```

my mistake was missing apostrophe. i wrote : $ci  . so posted data was the first  word. when i added the apostrophe value='$ci', posted data is now full category name. so its solved :)

Comment: Hoo boy... Are you really using `root` user for MySQL? And it has no password? Not good. Fix that before you do *anything* else.

Comment: thanks for that. i'm so much beginner thats why i have so many to learn. i will fix it immediately. Thank you